# Run sql files using batch file on a non-SQL server PC

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

Is it possible to [insert title here]? I'm currently running a test site on my local PC and I want to update the database running on Apache's MySQL.

Google isn't really helpful though, because all results it gives me are all for SQL server PCs.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*Apache's MySQL*". MySQL is from Oracle. "SQL Server" is also the name of a DBMS product from Microsoft so it's unclear to me which DBMS you are really using. In general you simply need a SQL client on the computer where you want to run the SQL script. Which SQL client that is and how you install it depends on the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, thanks. I got confused a little because I've been looking for a solution for hours now. Anyway, I'm using XAMPP to run both Apache and MySQL on my local PC.

Comment: If you have MySQL installed, you already have a command line client that you can run in batch mode: `mysql`